# In Highchart, why drilldown data of pie chart is not of same color?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

References Links: 
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

In column-drilldown main bar and its drilldown data bars colors are same.
Why this is not in Pie Drilldown?
Do I need to set color scheme for this?
Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `colorByPoint` flag to `false` for each drilldown.

Example:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        colorByPoint: false,
        id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        data: [...]
    },{
```

See this working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mg00wu3a/